# Verifier Rejected Class - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I'm making an application in Android Studio and keep getting a "java.lang.VerifyError". It's on a class (class Place) I made that I've declared with @Parcelize to pass an ArrayList containing Place objects. I know it is related to the writeToParel(Parcel, Int) method it's automatically generated but that's about all I can figure out.

I can't figure out why it keeps showing up, I've done the following recommended solutions and nothing helps: The following (solutions suggested on similar SO posts) did not work:

- Clean and re-build (even tried cleaning manually)
- Invalidate Caches &
  Restart IDE

I know the automatic "parcelization" is an experimental feature so maybe it's just a bug - if so what workarounds can I try?

The error starts when creating an object from the Place class I created. I copied the relevant part of Place.kt, log, and build.gralde below. Thanks in advance

**Place.kt**

```
@Parcelize
class Place constructor (var name:String, var placeID:String, var 
                     description:String, var photoRef:String,
                     var price:Int, var rating:Int,
                     var location:Array<Double>) : Parcelable {

var googleURL : String
var lat : Double
var lng : Double

// Initialization instructions
init{
    this.lat = location[0]
    this.lng = location[1]
    googleURL = makeGoogleMapsURL()
}
...
```

**Log**

```
06-18 15:55:19.174 5815-5815/com.example.daniel.digit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.daniel.digit, PID: 5815
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.example.daniel.digit.Place: void com.example.daniel.digit.Place.writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int) failed to verify: void com.example.daniel.digit.Place.writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int): [0x48] register v3 has type Precise Reference: java.lang.Double but expected Double (Low Half) (declaration of 'com.example.daniel.digit.Place' appears in /data/app/com.example.daniel.digit-5DnxZcCKWzN_9Wj-TMpmIQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk)
    at com.example.daniel.digit.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:79)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25883)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.daniel.digit"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:3.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure of the usage of your class but I see the error mentions the `Double` so my recommendation is:

- Unless you really need a `Array<Double>` which is equivalent to: `Double[]` in java, you can use: `DoubleArray` which translates to `double[]` (the primitive usage will let your class to be more easy to parcelize).

Also try to keep your class more simple. Use a `data class` if this class only purpose is to hold data and if all the data is needed you can remove the word: `constructor` from the definition.